# Maven; plugin or dependency is compatible with JDK 17?

Tags: maven, java-8, migration, maven-plugin, java-17

How can I determine if my Maven plugin or dependency is compatible with JDK 17?
I need to migrate my Java 8 Maven application to Java 17.
For example, docbkx-maven-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.agilejava.docbkx</groupId>
    <artifactId>docbkx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.xslthl</groupId>
            <artifactId>xslthl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.docbook</groupId>
            <artifactId>docbook-xml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0-all</version>
            <classifier>resources</classifier>
            <type>zip</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

thanks

I searched on Maven Central and the GitHub project, but there was no mention of the supported JDK versions for the Maven plugin docbkx-maven-plugin

Comment: Try to build on JDK17+...

Comment: I would really check it because the docbkx-maven-plugin is more than seven years old... and the question is why do you use it? No better alternatives?